# DuckDB: Does batch inserting data negatively effect performance after data has been inserted?

Tags: duckdb

I have a parquet file that is bigger than memory that I want to read into DuckDB.

When I batch insert into DuckDB (writing one Parquetfile row group at the time) **the resulting database is 4.97GB instead of 3.42GB** when inserting the full parquet file at once.

Will this effect query performance? and is there a way to vacuum the batch-inserted database to the same size as the entire parquet insert (running the `vacuum analyse main.new_tbl` does not reduce file size).

Does this type of writing affect query performance? I'm modelling a system where I do a large batch insert initially (perhaps a few million rows) then INSERT/"UPSERT" delta every 10 minutes but I'm worried this might fragment the duckdb database.

(For more information on insert per row group, see https://gist.github.com/bivald/e40a3c64daa1057629890b5dc493a001 - I didn't want to make this question much longer, but I can edit it in if you'd like)

Regards,
Niklas